# JavaScript hash URL with content loader div on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hash, load

I have created the hash load URL function in javascript, everything is perfect expected one issue, that is - I want, If I click on the URL `<div class="loader"</div>` will append. Is this basically a loader that will represent something loading.
I already using this code `$("body > div.content").append('<div class="loader"</div>');` but this loader only work when I reload the page.
I want when I click on `<a href="#page">CLICK HERE</a>` types click the i will also show loader.

How I achieve the goal and fix my code.
Please help me

```js
function loadcontent(hash) {
  if (hash == "") {
    hash = "./home.html";
  }
  $("html body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, "600", "swing");
  $("body > div.content").load("directory/" + hash);
}

$(window).on("hashchange", function() {
  loadcontent(location.hash.slice(1));
});

var url = window.location.href;
var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf("#") + 1);
if (hash === url) {
  hash = "./home.html";
}
$("body > div.content").append('<div class="loader"</div>');
$("div.content > div").load("directory/" + hash, function(responseTxt, statusTxt, jqXHR) {
  if (statusTxt == "success") {
    $("div.loader").remove(); return true;
  } else {
    if (statusTxt == "error") {
      $("div.loader").remove();
      alert("Error : " + jqXHR.status + " " + jqXHR.statusText);
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<a href="#page" onclick="loadcontent(hash)">CLICK HERE</a>
```

You might have to return false in `loadcontent()` if you don't want to redirect.

Comment: When I use onclick it not redirect the page, can you please update my script as you want to explain

Comment: return true below should solve it 

`if (statusTxt == "success") {     $("div.loader").remove();    return true;   } `